# Use gdb with Eigen c++ inlined function?

Tags: c++, gdb, eigen

I am encountering some problems when using gdb with Eigen, e.g.,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    Matrix<double, 5, 5> m;
    m << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
         4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
         7, 8, 9, 1, 2,
         1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
         4, 5, 6, 7, 8;

    std::cout << "m =" << std::endl << m << std::endl;
    std::cout << "m^{T} =" << std::endl << m.transpose() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

For the above code (the compiler is g++ 9.0, with gdb version 11.1), the problems are:

1. I can only call: `p m.transpose()` successfully while debugging, when I call other functions like `p m.trace()`, it shows that "Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined";
2. It seems that I cannot call overloaded operators that are defined in Eigen, like if i am calling `p m * m` in gdb, it will show that "No symbol "operator*" in current context."

I have made some investigations but none of the possible solutions I tried works, such as using set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O0 -fno-inline"). So I am wondering how to achieve the above two actions in gdb with Eigen if it is possible? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Hint: the `-ggdb` flag (or one of its variants) may help. Also possibly `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`. Also, a debug build may work better for debugging than an optimized build.

Comment: If `m.trace()` was never used in the program, then the function was probably never included in the executable, and thus gdb can't use it either.